# Protractor mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, protractor

We would like to test a chart component's zoom per mouse wheel.

I cannot find any way to trigger a mouse wheel, via protractor or javascript `browser.executeScript('... some javascript code')`;

Note: we do not need "scroll" function (scrollTo, scrollIntoView etc.), has to be specifically mouse wheel.

Is there any way to trigger mousewheel?

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
```

Info from Russian site (https://learn.javascript.ru/mousewheel)

Comment: This does not help.
addEventListener("wheel") listens to users mouse wheel action.
I need to trigger, programatically, a mouse wheel action.